# Mysql query runs very slow when using order by

Tags: mysql, performance

The following query takes 30 seconds to finish when having order by. Without order by it finish in 0.0035 seconds. I am already having an index on field "name". Field "id" is the primary key. I have 400,000 record in this table. Please help, what is wrong with the query when using order by.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE name IS NOT NULL 
AND name != '' 
AND ( status IS NULL OR status = '0' ) 
order by id desc 
limit 50
```

Update: (solution at the end )
Hi All, Thanks for the help. Below is some updates as you asked:

1. Below is the output of explain.

   id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra

   1   SIMPLE  users   range   name    name    258     NULL    226009  Using where; Using filesort
2. Yes, there are around 20 fields in this table.
3. Below are the indexes that I have:

   Keyname     Type    Cardinality     Field

   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     418099   id
   name    INDEX           411049  name

Solution:
It turns out the fields with null values are the reason. When making those 2 fields in the where condition to NOT NULL, it just takes .000x seconds. But the strange thing is, it increases to 29 seconds if I create an index of (status,name,id DESC) or (status,name,id).

Comment: at the very least, you should include the output of "explain" for your query.

Comment: Is there any change when you explicitly identify the columns you're querying?

Comment: Do you have a huge result set and is your `id` indexed?

Comment: how does it performs with order by id (without desc)?

Comment: @Paul Sanwald - I added the output of explain.

Comment: @George id is the primary key. Do I need to create a separate index for that?

Comment: @rene There is no change even if I remove "desc". it still takes around 30 secs

Comment: @Origin Thanks. It reduce 5 seconds, but stills seems something wrong as it takes 25 seconds when specifying the field name explicitly

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely have **compound index**. A single one containing all the fields you need as DBMSs can not really use more than one index on a single query.

An OR clause is not really index-friendly, so if you can I recommend setting `status` to **NOT NULL**. I assume NULL does not have any different meaning from the zero number. This will help a lot to actually use the index.

I do not know how much `name != ''` is optimized. Semantically equal would be `name > ''` (meaning it is later in the alphabet), may be this also save you some CPU cycles.

Then you have to decide the order in which your columns appear. A rule of thumb could be **cardinality**, the possible values a field can have.

By this:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX order1 (status, name, id DESC);
```

**Edit**

You don't need to delete indexes. MySQL will choose the best one very quickly and ignore the rest. They only cost disk space and some CPU cycles on `UPDATE`s. But if you do not need them in any circumstances you can remove them of course.

The long time is because the access to your table is slow. This is probably caused by dynamic length fields such as TEXT or BLOB. If you do not ALWAYS need these, you can move them to a twin auxiliary table like:

```
users (id, name, status, group_id)
profile (user_id, birthdate, gender, motto, cv)
```

This way the essential system-operations can be done with a restricted information about the user, and all the other stuff which is really **content** associated with the user only have to be used when it is really needed.

**Edit2**

You hint MySQL which index to use by specifying it (or more of them) like:

```
SELECT id, name FROM users USE INDEX (order1) WHERE name != '' and status = '0' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: As you said, I created an index "ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX namstatid (name, status, id DESC);". Now it takes 0.8 second if I select only fields within that 3 columns (name,status,id ). but If I use any columns other than that, it takes around 26 seconds. Also, should I delete the other indexes ( currently I have 2 index. one in status and other in name ).

Comment: When I use the "explain select id,someotherfield from users where WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND name != '' AND ( status IS NULL OR status = '0' ) order by id desc limit 50" it seems not using the index. So, it will obviously not going to use the index even after we move the data right? In that case, the problem will persist. As moving the data to sub-tables;modifying various other associated things is involved.. I would like to make sure this will work. The only time it uses the index is, if I just use only the field(s) which is in index. Please tell me your thoughts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @3iguru As I said in my post: `OR` means that the possible results can not be restricted to a continuous region inside the index. You will have two distinct regions: one for `NULL` and one for `0`. - This way MySQL can not take full advantage of indexes. - Changing the field to `NOT NULL` might help this.

Comment: Apologize, I already removed those OR parts and only using the below query: Explain SELECT id,name FROM users WHERE name != '' and status = '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30 . The output is "Extra: Using where; Using index; Using filesort Ref: null". When I include any other field which is not part of an index, it outputs "Extra: Using where; Using filesort Ref: null". It means when I use any additional fields, it don't use index. I also tested by making the fields not null. Please tell me what you think.

Comment: @3iguru I edited my answer, please also note the possibility of using `WHERE name > ''` instead of `!=` Also note that I recommended: `(status, name, id DESC)` instead of `(name,status,id)`

Comment: Here is the strange thing. I did all the steps ( 2 fields not null, index creation, suggesting index, >='' yet it was taking 29 seconds to finish if I user "select *" or use any field that is not in index. But without any indexes but setting those 2 fields to not null ( name, status ) the below query takes just .0009 seconds "select * from users where name!='' and status='0' order by id desc limit 50". So, as you said, the issue seems to be null value fields and using OR. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

without having an explain it is hard to say, but most probably you also need an index on
the "status" column. slowness on a single table query almost always comes down to the query doing a full table scan as opposed to using an index.

try doing:

```
explain SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE name IS NOT NULL 
AND name != '' 
AND ( status IS NULL OR status = '0' ) 
order by id desc 
limit 50
```

and post the output. you'll probably see it is doing a full table scan, because it doesn't have an index for status. [here's some documentation on using "explain"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). If you want more background, [this is a nice article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/) on the kind of problem you are having.

Comment: Hi, Below is the output of explain. Below is the output of explain.
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  users  range  name  name  258  NULL  226009  Using where; Using filesort